# MongoDB 4.1 TotalRecords and Data in Aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, count, aggregate

I´m facing a problem because I´m new at mongo but I want to solve it.

I have different collections which I aggregate with lookups which is working perfect.
But now, I want to have the sum of total records in the header of my result.

My first problem now is that my actor relation is an array and my second problem is that I don´t know how to divide TotalCount and data from each other in the response.

The result should look like:

```
{
 "totalRecords": 12,
 "itemsPerPage": 10,

 "docs": {
    "_id": "7429437848adssk",
    "title": "abc"
    "actors" [
         {"name": "Mr.x" },
         {"name": "Mrs.Y"}
     ]
 }
}
```

I solved my aggregation without the total count with the following stages:

1. unwind actors
2. lookup on actors
3. group with $first on first collection and $addToSet of the actors

Result on my response without count is as expected but if I add a $count into group it counts the actors and on 1 document with 2 actors it counts 2. But I want to have a count of each document.

Could someone provide me with a simple working example on my problem?

Comment: Take a look `$facet` operator

Comment: Do you have a small example for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add these 3 steps at the end of your aggregation

```
{
  $facet: {
    totalRecords: [
      {
        $count: "totalRecords"
      }
    ],
    docs: [
      {
      $match: {}
      }
    ]
  }
},
{
  $unwind: "$docs"
},
{
  $addFields: {
    totalRecords: {
      $arrayElemAt: [
        "$totalRecords.totalRecords",
        0
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MnVPI9G6qH_)